# Converting a 2D vector to a 4D vector

Tags: matlab

In a machine learning task, I need a `4D` single type data to fed for training. But my data is in a `2D` format. Would you please show me how to do this conversion?

Input:
for data of 28th row,

```
val(28,1) = 1.5

val(28,2) = 2.7
```

output:

```
val(:,:,1,28) = 1.5

val(:,:,2,28) = 2.7
```

I'm looking for your advice in this regard.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you even try `val(1,1,1,28)=1.5`?

Comment: @adrian : I have around 4000 2d  data in val. How could I automatically assign these amount of 2d data in their equivalent 4d vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) is the function to swap the dimensions.

```
out = permute(val,[4,3,2,1]);
%or out = permute(val,[3,4,2,1]);
```